# method not returning anything

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I created a method for returning a certain row and there is no error or anything just the method not returning any data from the database.

Here is where I invoke the method:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost/old marketplace website/">
    <?php echo $controller->getTableData($table, $column, $columnValue, $rowTitle); ?>
</a>
```

And here is what the method `getTableData()` looks like:

```
public function getTableData($table, $column, $columnValue, $rowTitle)
{
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $column = ? ");

    $query->bindValue(1,$columnValue);    
    $query->execute();

    $f = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $result = $f['$rowTitle'];

    return $result;
}
```

How do I need to adjust my method to have it return the desired data?

Comment: How about you inlcude your function inside a php tag? 
`<?php //your function ?>`

Comment: In the actual class file it is in a php tag... i just didn't include the tag in the post.

Comment: `var_dump($f)` to make sure you are getting a result from your query. If not, that's what you need to address.

Answer (score 5):

Try removing quotes from the following line:

```
$result = $f['$rowTitle'];
```

You're looking for a column with the name equal to the *value* of `$rowTitle`, rather than a column with the name `'$rowTitle'`. Remove the single quotes to use the value of the variable `$rowTitle`:

```
$result = $f[$rowTitle];
```

For reference, see:

- [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: Not only that, if anyone writes `'`, PHP will try to **literally** parse it, it is not the same as `"`

Comment: Still didn't return anything

Comment: I think with the info you've given this is the best answer you'll get. Try echoing what is retrieved from the db?